# webview inside the listview in Android, javascript arithmetic operations not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am working in webview. I have a toggle button in my web page and when I click that button it will call the javascript function.
 But it not properly working as expected. When I call that function when it come to addition operation it stuck. The only thing I done differently is I have webview inside listview.

```
function fnTogglePositive(obj){  
    oTable = document.getElementById("tblData");  
    obj.innerHTML = "ALL";  
    var i = 0;  
        fnCheck(0,6);   
    }           
    else{                           
    obj.innerHTML = "POSITIVE";         
    }
}

function fnCheck(i,n){  
    var k = parseInt(i) + 1;  
    if(i<n){  
       document.getElementById("txt").value = k ;  
    }  
    else  
       return 0;  
}
```

I loaded this javascript function in webview inside the list view. When I called the
    fnTogglePositive function it's not calculating the value, when the webview is inside the listview.

> I created a separate activity which contains only the webview its working fine.
>   I can able to figure out where it stuck. The function call happened but it stuck  in calculating the
>       value.  Why it stuck in this point?

Why this issue happened?

Answer (score 0):

you need to build a bridge between you android code and JavaScript code.
Check this [guide](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/binding-javascript-and-android-code-example/)

Comment: 'var k = parseInt(i) + 1;'  this line causing trouble. And the strange thing is it working in separate activity only has web view.  But when it comes list view containing lost of webview it fails to work. I got Uncaught reference error : fnTogglePositive is not defined. I tried to alter my javascript code . if i remove the 'var k =parseInt(i) + 1' . it not throwing the uncaught reference error. I need to know the reason.Thanks in advanced.